# Analisar 4 selects e exibir mensagem

Tags: sql, if, sql-insert, where

Fala ai pessoal, blz?

Gostaria de saber como fazer a seguinte lógica em SQL:

```
if( 1 = select * from tblA or  
    1 = select * from tblB or  
    1 = select * from tblC or  
    1 = select * from tblD or )
    Print 'ABC'
```

Comment: Sua pergunta não está clara. Você não informou o `SGBD` utilizando nem o que seria o `Print`. Você quer mostrar no console? Por que não usar uma `query` para isso?

Comment: Então, o quero apenas um modo como fazer isso, não sei mt de SQL, se tiver outra foma(mais eficiente) pode mandar, será bem vinda :D

Comment: O print não importa é apenas uma mensagem qualquer que vou escolher, acredito que para resolver isso, isto é irrelevante

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 'ABC'
 WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1
                FROM tblA)
    OR EXISTS(SELECT 1
                FROM tblB)
    OR EXISTS(SELECT 1
                FROM tblC)
    OR EXISTS(SELECT 1
                FROM tblD)
```

Comment: A sim, entendi.
Você parece ter bastante experiência na área de Desenvolvimento, gostaria de saber se tem como você me ajudar num problema que tenho:

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação(não só desenvolvedor), mas programo razoavelmente bem em c# .
Vamos lá:

O problema é o seguinte
Tenho uma Tabela chamada Escala:
http://prntscr.com/mp25qt <-- Design dela

Comment: Quero criar uma trigger que Bloqueie o insert ou update nela 
Se tiver alguma escala no mesmo intervalo e for do mesmo tipo.
Conseguiu entender bem? 
Pode me ajudar?

Comment: @GustavoPedro então, tem algumas perguntas sobre `triggers` que bloqueiam aqui no SO já, mas sem saber qual o `SGBD` não consigo nem te indicar quais são

Comment: É SQL Server 2012

Comment: https://pedrogalvaojunior.wordpress.com/2013/05/02/entendendo-o-comportamento-de-trigger-dml-instead-of-no-microsoft-sql-server-2008-r2-e-2012/

Comment: A sim, vou dar uma estudada lá vlw :D